# How do we integrate $x\sqrt{x^3 + 1}$?

Tags: integration

Tried to use integration by parts but just keep going round in circles. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: is it $x  \sqrt {x^3+1}$ and if so, there doesn't seem to be elementary antiderivative

Comment: Please use MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'm seeing the answer has elliptic integrals... It may not have an elementary antiderivative. Source: WolframAlpha

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, and perhaps a little more transparent than just stating the result in terms of elliptic functions, we can find an antiderivative by expanding the square root and integrating the powers of x.

This leads to

$$a(x) = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k} x^{3 k+2}}{3 k+2}$$

This infinite sum can be expressed by a hypergeometric function

$$a(x) =\frac{1}{2} x^2 \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};-x^3\right)$$

Hence the function $a(x)$ is analytic in $x$ except for a branch cut from $x = -1$ to $x = -\infty$.

**EDIT**

We can obtain a possibly different antiderivative by writing

$$\sqrt{x^3+1}=x^{3/2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^3}+1}$$

expanding into negative powers and integrating, viz.

$$b(x)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k} x^{\frac{7}{2}-3 k}}{\frac{7}{2}-3 k}$$

which can be expressed as

$$b(x) = \frac{2}{7} x^{7/2} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{7}{6},-\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{6};-\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

This expression holds even for $x\gt 0$.

*Corollary*

There should be a standard transformation of the hypergeometric function showing some equivalence of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$. Or, inverting the reasoning, we have just derived this transformation.

Not really, we must be careful here. In fact, $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are not identical in the overlaping region of definition $x > 0$ but differ by a constant (which is permissible for antiderivatives):

$$b(x) = a(x) + c$$

where

$$ c = \lim_{x\to 0} \, b(x) = -\frac{2 \left(\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)-6 \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}{21 \sqrt{\pi }} \simeq 0.739174$$

Comment: That is a very cute expression for something that can look as a beast expressed in the elliptic integrals. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

a possible answer can be found by Mathematica:
$$\frac{2 \left(x^5+x^2-3^{3/4} \sqrt{-\sqrt[6]{-1} \left(x+(-1)^{2/3}\right)}
   \sqrt{(-1)^{2/3} x^2+\sqrt[3]{-1} x+1} \left((-1)^{5/6} F\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-(-1)^{5/6}
   (x+1)}}{\sqrt[4]{3}}\right)|\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)+\sqrt{3} E\left(\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-(-1)^{5/6}
   (x+1)}}{\sqrt[4]{3}}\right)|\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)\right)\right)}{7
   \sqrt{x^3+1}}$$

Comment: I don't see how that is a helpful answer.

Comment: What do $F$ and $E$ mean on your answer @Dr?

Comment: it is possible that someone other can see it and thank you for your $-1$

Comment: these are special elliptic functions

Comment: Ah okay. Nice to know the answer in it's entire form +1

Comment: The question was not "what do you get if you throw this integral into Wolfram alpha" but "how do you compute this integral"? If it cannot be done by elimentary methods, then that should be part of the answer.

Comment: i have not thrown it in WolframAlpha, i used my own program Mathematica

Comment: That is not particularly relevant. The point is that the question was asking for a methodology to compute the integral, not only the answer itself. At the very least you should post the Mathematica code you used.

Comment: @A.W.Grossbard I agree, the answer should not include only an evaluation of mathematica. It should have more detail

Comment: some other persons on this forum did the same thing, you can search for such kinds of answers

Comment: That is not a reason to do it! I agree, their are plenty of bad answers on this site. It would be better if there were fewer.

Comment: we should concentrate our energy to help the askers here to solve their mathematical problems,ok?